# Unable to set multiple headers - Content-Type & Accept while using karate

Tags: karate

The request that I am trying to test is having 2 mandatory headers - Content-Type: 'application/json' and Accept: 'application/json'.

When I run below scenario , it gives me status code 400 saying Mandatory header Accept is missing - which is correct behavior.

```
Scenario: Validating test

  * configure headers = { Content-Type: 'application/json'}
And url testURL
  And request { "abc": {"xyz": "fgfdgf"}}
  When method post
```

But , when I run below scenario , it still gives me status code 400 saying Mandatory header Content-Typeis missing - which is NOT right behavior.

Scenario: Validating test

```
  * configure headers = { Content-Type: 'application/json',Accept:'application/json'}
And url testURL
  And request { "abc": {"xyz": "fgfdgf"}}
  When method post
  Then status 200
```

Can someone suggest what is wrong in the second scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Content-Type` will be automatically set by Karate, you don't need to set it - if the request body is clearly JSON.

The mistake you are making is that the `-` character is not valid as a JSON (JS) key-name, so this would work:

```
* configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json' }
```

Observe the quotes around `Content-Type`.

Comment: I tried it with the quotes but its still not working for me. If I set only Content-Type then it works but if I provide both Content-Type & Accept , then it does not work.

Comment: @Richa - maybe it is a bug on your server :) but I give up - it is time to point you to these instructions, and all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by configuring charset as null :

- configure charset = null

By default , charset is taken as UTF-8. So in order to explicitly define content-type we need to set charset as null in Background.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, you should really check if you have a bug